# decompiling .jar file using jd-cmd API

Tags: java, decompiling, jd-cmd

So I was searching for a command line tool to de-compile .jar files, I found this "jd-cmd" at https://github.com/kwart/jd-cmd and it worked fine, but now I saw it has an api that I can use, I can't seem to do it the wright way.
 I am working on intellij IDE, added the external jars  to my project, all I want is that the output will be at a folder of my choice in the filesystem just like it works at the command line with no problems.
here's an example code I tried from the idea that didn't do the job:

```
import java.io.File;
import jd.core.input.JDInput;
import jd.core.input.ZipFileInput;
import jd.core.output.DirOutput;
import jd.core.output.JDOutput;
import jd.ide.intellij.JavaDecompiler;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaDecompiler javaDecompiler = new JavaDecompiler();
        //choose input plugin for your decompiled file (class, zip, directory)
        JDInput jdIn = new ZipFileInput("path/to/myFavorityLib.jar");
        //choose output plugin (zip, directory, console)
        JDOutput jdOut = new DirOutput(new File("/tmp/decompiled"));
        //decompile
        jdIn.decompile(javaDecompiler, jdOut);
    }
}
```

This code didnt generate decompiled files at "/tmp/decompiled"

Comment: I've voted to close this because the question is basically, "why doesn't this code work", but you've not provided anything like enough code to allow another developer to replicate your problem. In order to achieve this you should use and include a maven pom or gradle build file so that we get the same dependency you're using and run the app in the same way you do.

Comment: Just trying to guess (as the previous comment says, that's all we can do...): maybe the directory /tmp/decompiled does not exist and that prevents the output file to be created.

Comment: hey friend , listen as you probaly know my project should not be configured as a maven project , so no pom or gradle build is required , the problem with this open source is - to my opinion - that i am just not using it the correct way, to solve this question one should try to run it and make it work on his computer and then tell us what was the way is has done it.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i have managed to do it . 
it was a dependency problem , the github developer mentioned that jd-lib folder should be added as a dependency library , but actually it dosent matter that much ,you need  to add a jar file :after doing all the instructions and downloding what ever maven will give you, at the folder jd-cli there a downloaded jar  "jd-cli.jar" , use this as a dependency for your project and it work just fine!